# The %typemap directive doesn't been compiled in SWIG

Tags: c, python-3.x, swig

I'm using SWIG 3.0 to wrap my C project to python. I had used some directives in interface file such as %extend, %inline, %array_class and they worked fine. I'm trying to use %typemap to solve double pointer argument. However there is **neither any change in example_wrap.c** after adding %typemap lines **nor any error message** when swig generate the wrapped code.

I had tried changing the order between other directives and I'm sure I edit the correct file. Is there extra option needed when `swig -python -Iinclude example.i`? Or does anyone have idea how to debug this?

EDIT:
Here is my code after removing unnecessary lines. I don't think the problem is here because the result is still the same even if the syntax is wrong in the brackets.

example.i:

```
%module example
%{
#include "example.h"
%}
%include "example.h"

typedef long int ssize_t;
typedef long int time_t;

%typemap(in) qry_t **q (qry_t *ptr) {
   $1 = &ptr;
}
```

terminal:

```
[feng@dev test]$ swig -python -Iinclude mbsrch.i
[feng@dev test]$
```

I also tried installing SWIG again in case there are missing files, but it still not work.

Comment: `%typemap` does work. Please can you show a minimal example of what isn't working as you expected so we can understand where it's gone wrong.

Comment: @Flexo Thanks for your apply. I added the info.

Comment: The error is exactly in the file you showed, so I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your typedefs and typemaps need to be visible before the `%include` that they're going to be used by, something like this:

```
%module example
%{
#include "example.h"
%}

typedef long int ssize_t;
typedef long int time_t;

%typemap(in) qry_t **q (qry_t *ptr) {
   $1 = &ptr;
}

%include "example.h"
```

You can validate this with `-debug-tmsearch` argument for SWIG, which shows how matches are being applied.

Comment: Thank you very much! This actually works. BTW, doesn't SWIG need to know the structure information first?

Comment: @feng no, with the typemaps it basically does a smart copy and paste into the output wrapper it generates, so as long as the real C++ or C compiler knows the structure information you're good. It's basically opaque to SWIG when processing arguments though.

Comment: Then why does the order affect it? By implementation reason?

Comment: Everytime SWIG sees `qry_t**` it 'pastes' the current best matching typemap into the output it generates, as it goes.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your explanation!